# How can I show special characters in a terminal when I copy a file from my local Mac to my remote Ubuntu server?

Tags: 12.04

When I copy a webpage from my local machine (Mac) to my remote server (Ubuntu), the special characters in the text are ending up in squares in a browser or question-mark-symbols in the terminal.

I tried copying them with scp or ftp; same problem.

I checked the language on the server: LANG=en_US.UTF-8. This seems right and shouldn't be the problem anyway because when I edit the file in the terminal on the server, special characters display as they should.

Already searched for hours but can't find the solution. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you using high ASCII characters instead of HTML entities?

Comment: Yes, I just have some raw text in a html file with é in it. Not &eacute; This should be possible right?

Answer (score 1):

Using UTF-8 can solve a lot of that problem, but you still have to use HTML entities for reserved XML characters (ampersand, less-than, greater-than). So, either use HTML entities or serve the webpage with an HTTP header that says it's UTF-8. That could be done with an HTML header or META tag:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Or, in the Ubuntu web server change the default encoding:

Apache: `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

nginx: `charset utf-8;`

On the terminal, you know that the server is using UTF-8 (`locale`), so make sure that your SSH client is set up correctly. For example, if using Putty, we have to set Putty's character set:

Putty: `Window->Translation->Remote character set: UTF-8`

Otherwise, it will use ISO-8859-1.

[image: Putty Translation]

And check what format the editor is using.

`file file.ext`

We should see "UTF-8 Unicode text" if the editor is writing UTF-8 files.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't think that's the solution. I already had this meta tag in the file and I doubt if it is a apache thing because the I can't see the special characters even if I open the file n terminal.

Comment: Sorry - I neglected the terminal portion... updated answer. :)

Comment: http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/

Comment: I've tried but with no luck. Not with scp via terminal, not with an ftp program.

Comment: However, you did put me on the right track! When I checked the settings of my editor, I saw the text encoding was by default on Western. This fixed it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah! Yes... so many variables at play with encoding. Accepted?

Comment: Updated your find in the answer for the benefit of askubuntu.com